# 'List<Choice>' does not contain a definition for 'ChoiceId ' and no extension...are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Title is just a part of the error, here is one of many error:

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'ChoiceId' and no extension method 'ChoiceId' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am trying to unit test a list of RepaymentPlan as stated below. But I can not seem to fetch the rest of the values in that list since I get red underline error below those keys (I have wrapped those keys with ** ** in unit test below. Something wrong I am doing and not sure how to solve it.

Still learning and fresh new to programming so hopefully you guys can guide me in the right way. Really appreciate your help.

Here is what I have:

***Models:***

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Repayment
    {
      public int Amount { get; set; }
      public string DueDate { get; set; }
      public string RepaymentId { get; set; }
    }

   public class Choice
   {
      public string ChoiceId { get; set; }
      public List<Repayment> Repayments{ get; set; }
   }

   public class RepaymentPlan
   {
      public List<Choice> Choices{ get; set; }
   }
}
```

---

***Repositories:***

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Project.Models;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;


namespace Project.Repositories
{
   public class OrderRepository
   {
       private static List<RepaymentPlan> _RepaymentPlan;

       static OrderRepository()
       {
           _RepaymentPlan = new List<RepaymentPlan>();

          _RepaymentPlan.Add(new RepaymentPlan 
          {
             Choices = new List<Choice>
                        {
                            new Choice
                            {
                                ChoiceId = "cho1",
                                Repayments = new List<Repayment>
                                                {
                                                    new Repayment
                                                    {
                                                        Amount = 200,
                                                        DueDate = "2018-06-01"
                                                    }, 
                                                    new Repayment
                                                    {
                                                        Amount = 100,
                                                        DueDate = "2018-08-01",
                                                    }
                                                }
                            }, 
                            new Choice
                            {
                                ChoiceId = "cho2",
                                Repayments = new List<Repayment>
                                                {
                                                    new Repayment
                                                    {
                                                        RepaymentId = "Choice1",
                                                        Amount = 300,
                                                        DueDate = "2018-10-01"
                                                    }, 
                                                    new Repayment
                                                    {
                                                        RepaymentId = "Choice2",
                                                        Amount = 150,
                                                        DueDate = "2018-11-01"
                                                    }, 
                                                }
                            }                                             
                        },
             });
}
```

---

*** Unit test ***

```
[Test]
public void ListRepaymentPlan()
{
     // Arrange
     var controller = new CaseController();
     var expectedResult = new List<RepaymentPlan>();
     var repaymentPlan = new RepaymentPlan()
     {
          Choices = new List<Choice>
                    {
                        new Choice
                        {
                            ChoiceId = "cho1",
                            Repayments = new List<Repayment>
                                            {
                                                new Repayment
                                                {
                                                    Amount = 200,
                                                    DueDate = "2018-06-01"
                                                }, 
                                                new Repayment
                                                {
                                                    Amount = 100,
                                                    DueDate = "2018-08-01"
                                                }, 
                                            }
                       }, 
                        new Choice
                        {
                             ChoiceId = "cho2",
                             Repayments = new List<Repayment>
                                            {
                                                new Repayment
                                                {
                                                    RepaymentId = "Choice1",
                                                    Amount = 300,
                                                    DueDate = "2018-10-01"
                                                }, 
                                                new Repayment
                                                {
                                                    RepaymentId = "Choice2",
                                                    Amount = 150,
                                                    DueDate = "2018-11-01"
                                                }, 
                                            }
                        }                                             
                    },

            };
            expectedResult.Add(RepaymentPlan );

     // Act
     var actionResult = controller.FindRepaymentPlan("578", "156");
     var result = (List<RepaymentPlan >)actionResult;

     // Assert
     for (var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
     {
         Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices , result[i].Choices);
         Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices.**ChoiceId**, result[i].Choices.**ChoiceId**);
         Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices.**ChoiceId**.Repayments, result[i].Choices.**ChoiceId**.Repayments);
         Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices.**Repayments**.Amount, result[i].Choices.**Repayments**.Amount);
         Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices.**Repayments**.DueDate, result[i].Choices.**Repayments**.DueDate);
     }
 }
```

---

** Updated unit test **

```
        // Assert
        for (var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices, result[i].Choices);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices[0].ChoiceId, result[i].Choices[0].ChoiceId);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices[0].Repayments, result[i].Choices[0].Repayments);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices, result[i].Choices);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices[1].ChoiceId, result[i].Choices[1].ChoiceId);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices[1].Repayments, result[i].Choices[1].Repayments);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Choices` is a `List<>` so you need to index it too, something like this:

```
expectedResult[i].Choices[0].ChoiceId
```

However, you'd have to loop around those inner values too. It's much easier to use [`CollectionAssert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx):

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
```

Comment: Sweeet that fixed the second line, but what about the rest like this one : `    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult[i].Choices[0].ChoiceId.**Repayments**, result[i].Choices.ChoiceId.**Repayments**);`

Comment: Do I need to fetch the keys Amount and Duedate inside Repayment list in order to grab the values? As you can see above that I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you want to use your code above, or if you replace your entire loop with the code in my answer... no.

Comment: So in order to test everything there is in RepaymentPlan-List I have to do what I have done above? (See updated version above, please)

Comment: No, for the unit test to work, *all you need* is `CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);`

Comment: Weird that worked, if you have time, could you explain why that worked? Did it test all the keys and values were equal with one and another?

Comment: Ahh did not see that, sorry. Anyway, thank you so much for your help and have a lovely day! =D